# How to conditionally an id value iteratively to dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like below, and I was wondering how to programmatically add a new column conditionally based off of the first occurrence of a value.

The data I am actually using is a loop loading various excel files in a directory using `ldply(myfiles, function(x) read_excel(x, col_names = FALSE, range = "sheetname!A1:F22"))`. Below is a simplified version of this problem.

```
#Creating dataset
id<- c('1', '2', '3')
first_name= c("Name", "John", "Sue", "Bob", "Name", "Erin", "Becky", "Name", "Robert")
value= c(NA, 60, 0, 100, NA, 29, 49, NA, 5)
df<- data.frame(first_name, value)
df

  first_name value
1       Name    NA
2       John    60
3        Sue     0
4        Bob   100
5       Name    NA
6       Erin    29
7      Becky    49
8       Name    NA
9     Robert     5
```

I would like to use the list, `id`, to create a new column based off of the first occurrence of the condition `df[first_name == 'Name']`. So the rows 1:4 should be 1 below until the second occurrence of the condition `df[first_name == 'Name']`, where the id would be 2 and so on.

```
  first_name value id
1       Name    NA  1
2       John    60  1
3        Sue     0  1
4        Bob   100  1
5       Name    NA  2
6       Erin    29  2
7      Becky    49  2
8       Name    NA  3
9     Robert     5  3
```

Comment: it's just `df$id <- cumsum(df$first_name=="Name")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(id = cumsum(is.na(value)))
#   first_name value id
#1       Name    NA  1
#2       John    60  1
#3        Sue     0  1
#4        Bob   100  1
#5       Name    NA  2
#6       Erin    29  2
#7      Becky    49  2
#8       Name    NA  3
#9     Robert     5  3
```

Comment: But that counts the NA not the occurrences of Name which the OP asked for. In this case they are the same, but not in general.